# How to fix "attributeerror module 'numba' has no attribute 'core'"

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, numba, sktime

I am using the package sktime and I wanted to use the RocketClassifier. Somehow when I run `from sktime.classification.kernel_based import RocketClassifier` from the python console it works. But when I run the code in a Jupyter Notebook (VS Code) I get following error: `attributeerror module 'numba' has no attribute 'core`.
I have numba version 58.0.4. Have someone maybe a solution for that or can someone explain me, why it is not working?

Comment: Could you share a piece of code that reproduces the error? That would make it a lot easier to help you

Comment: It is just: `from sktime.classification.kernel_based import RocketClassifier` but like I said, this error is just appearing in VS Code when you're working there in a Jupyter Notebook.